# Install REPL-y clojure - lein compile doesn't work

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to install [REPL-y](https://github.com/trptcolin/reply). The lein project is working correctly, but when I try to run `lein compile` this happens:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.KeywordLookupSite.(ILclojure/lang/Keyword;)V

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: could you include more of the stacktrace, the branch your used (i presume 'master') and the commands you ran to invoke it?

Comment: ohh and what version of leiningen did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the project page:

> REPLy is now part of leiningen, as of the 2.x preview series. It's definitely your best bet for installation and Clojure development in general.

So perhaps using leiningen 2 will accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, I saw it the evening before, but forgot to come and post here: D, sorry about that, thanks for the reply.

[] s